# Storing objects as Item in Collection

Tags: c#

If I have 2 collections to run through and I wanna keep track of them, what is the best way to do so?

`BusinessObject1` can have `Int32` IDs such as this 1,2,3,4,5
`BusinessObject2` can have `String` IDs such as this "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"

I want to be able to keep a list of these objects whenever they are used and loop through them to check if they exist in the collection. So a realistic scenario can be this:

Item 1: 1, "Test 1"
Item 2: 2, "Test 1"
Item 3: 2, "Test 2"
Item 4: 3, "Test 2"

I can't use a dictionary since the keys need to be unique. This is a many-to-many relationship.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Keys need to be unique? Do you mean yours aren't? A dictionary's have to be for sure. Otherwise you can use any normal collection, and use `.Any()`, assuming ID is a member.

Comment: He is saying because keys need to be unique... he cant use it. His example makes that obvious

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship. I know keys need to be unique. I thought that was clear. I guess not

Comment: His items 1 and 2 seem to be identical, which could be why a dictionary won't work, but he mentions wanting to look for them in the collection, which implies that he doesn't want duplicates. Very confusing.

Comment: This is very confusing. I am still not sure if his set of business objects can have duplicate keys or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a List of Tuples

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> myCollection = new List<Tuple<int, string>>()
{
    {1, "Test 1"},
    {1, "Test 1"},
    {2, "Test 2"},
    {3, "Test 2"}
};
```

**Edit**: Adding example iteration

```
foreach(var tuple in myCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
}
```

**Edit**: Added Linq example

This will get you a list of all the Tuples with the pseudo-key of `1`

```
var ones = myCollection.Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not even certain if he's asking what to put them in, and even if he is, the int and string probably need to be replaced by `BusinessObject1` and `BusinessObject2`. Not that I blame you, I just don't think enough data has been provided for an accurate answer to be produced.

Comment: @Magus if this is the case he should just use a List<BusinessObject1> and linq.... Like NathanAldenSr's answer, but I'm not sure why the OP would even have to ask the question, unless he doesn't know Linq... or  how lists work. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use LINQ?

```
IEnumerable<BusinessObject1> businessObjects = ...;

if (businessObjects.Any(arg => arg.Id == 1))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store two types in the same list you can do something like this which uses List where you can change "object" to be a common base object that you may be using.

http://dotnetfiddle.net/a3lEx4